# Cleaning data by adding/removing characters to a string when it meets certain conditions T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, data-cleaning

I'm looking for help with cleaning a column in my data set so that I can join to another table.

The first data set is my complete data and includes what we call "**reference_numbers**" which relate to a specific case. Here is a dummy sample:

| reference_number | case_opened | case_closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01353568-00000001 | 11/01/2021 | 03/02/2022 |
| 09736473-00000009 | 21/04/2005 | 19/07/2021 |
| 05839576-00000012 | 13/09/2014 | 19/12/2017 |
| 09364857-00000006 | 13/09/2014 | 19/12/2017 |

As you can see, the "reference_number" is 8 digits then hyphen (-) and then another 8 digits. This is how a reference number should look.

My second data set is full of the same "reference_numbers". However, there is inconsistencies in the character length as they are often written differently by individuals:

| reference_number | Case_workers |
| --- | --- |
| 1353568-00000001 | 5 |
| 09736473-9 | 10 |
| 5839576-12 | 7 |
| 09364857-000000006 | 4 |

- The first reference_number in the second data set is missing the
  first "0"
- The second reference_number in the second data set is missing seven "0" after the hyphen
- The third reference_number in the second data set is missing both the first "0" and six "0" after the hyphen
- The fourth reference_number in the second data set has too many digits after the hyphen (there is supposed to be seven 0's)

I want to be able to join the first data set onto the second data set using the reference_number. However, I need to clean them first. Is this possible and is there any efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You can do this, just have to use a few expressions. Charindex to find position of the hyphen, len/left/right/substring to ocunt numbers and add/remove zeroes as needed.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Thanks for the info - would you be able to provide code for the 4 examples I've given? Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the rules are so specific, you could try to use a combination of `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT 
    t.reference_number,
    STRING_AGG(RIGHT('00000000'+s.value,8),'-') new_reference_number
FROM dbo.SecondTable t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.reference_number,'-') s
GROUP BY t.reference_number
;
```

Using the sample data you posted, the results are:

```
╔════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║  reference_number  ║ new_reference_number ║
╠════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 09364857-000000006 ║ 09364857-00000006    ║
║ 09736473-9         ║ 09736473-00000009    ║
║ 1353568-00000001   ║ 01353568-00000001    ║
║ 5839576-12         ║ 05839576-00000012    ║
╚════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Neither STRING_SPLIT nor STRING_AGG guarantee order. Beware!

Comment: @SMor True. But if the op is using azure SQL Database, `STRING_SPLIT` has a new `enable_ordinal` argument that returns just that. And `STRING_AGG` has an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Lamak Hello, I'm having an issue where the reference number keeps duplicating in the same cell e.g. 09364857-00000006-09364857-00000006-09364857-00000006. Do you know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

```
select reference_number,
CONCAT(left(reference_number, charindex('-', reference_number) - 1),'-',RIGHT(CONCAT('000000000',right(reference_number, len(reference_number) - charindex('-', reference_number))),9)) as NewReferenceNumber
from YourSecondTableName
```

| Reference_Number | New_Reference_Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1353568-00000001 | 1353568-000000001 |
| 09736473-9 | 09736473-000000009 |
| 5839576-12 | 5839576-000000012 |
| 09364857-000000006 | 09364857-000000006 |